# Log fetch on time stamp basiss

Tags: linux, awk

As am facing issue while fetching the log from linux box. My log type as bellow.

```
22-12-2016 13:11:10:324 com.tibco.jtc.ems.JTCLogger::traceMessage() [INFO ] - JTOP: (COUK--141556628-1482412267051) received message: TextMessage={ Header={ JMSMessageID={ID:IRPR03-SB-01.1B458279A852BC1C6BA:6511017} JMSDestination={Topic[$TMP$.IRPR03-CB-01.573D582798FB3554656D.4722]} JMSReplyTo={null} JMSDeliveryMode={PERSISTENT} JMSRedelivered={false} JMSCorrelationID={COUK--141556628-1482412267051} JMSType={null} JMSTimestamp={Thu Dec 22 13:11:10 GMT 2016} JM
```

Am using command like below.

```
awk -F ' ' '($2 -ge "13:11:10" && $2 -le "13:11:20") {print}' JTC.log > Sidd_JTC.log
```

As per comment I tried one command as below.

```
start="13:11:10*"
end="13:11:20*"
awk -v start="${start}" -v end="${end}" '$2 >= start && $2 <= end' JTC.log > Sidd_JTC.log
```

Its giving nearly correct logs but its taking time stamp less than one which i mentioned. Like  if give end time `13:11:20` its giving only till `13:11:19`.

Thank you all.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. That'd be multiple lines including some that do and some that don't fall within and on your boundaries. The reason your last awk command is failing btw is the `*` at the end of your start/end time variables - not sure what you think you're doing with that but get rid of it as it's causing you to compare the variable string `13:11:20*` with the input data string `13:11:20:` and so the result is dependent on the relative alphabetic order of `*` vs `:` and it seems unlikely that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the command should look like this:

```
awk '$2 >= "13:11:10" && $2 <= "13:11:20"' file.log
```

If you want to use variables:

```sh
start="13:11:10"
end="13:11:20"
awk -v start="${start}" -v end="${end}" '$2 >= start && $2 <= end' file.log
```

Comment: yes it will work but if you check the log am end up getting till '13:11:19' but am not able to get '13:11:20'. Can you please guide me to fix this issue

Comment: Use `end="13:11:21"` and then check `$2 < end`. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: nope, not obvious. we'll get the timing from other person so have to search from exact time.

and for 1 type of logs it comes for 1 min minus but for other type of logs the above command sometimes give the exact log and sometimes it doesnt

Comment: Why didn't you add that information including examples to your question if it is so important? Please edit it.

Comment: Dear friend after your command am facing this, if you know please guide me.  will put it across now. As am building one script its used for many other logs not only same type. If i got will adopt same thing to all. Any way thank you for the answer.

Comment: Just edit your question and demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Sure will do now.

Comment: Don't use `"13:11:10*"` use `"13:11:10"`, as I showed

Comment: @hek2mgl: Can awk interpret  string "13:11:10" as time  ?  and  awk '$2 >= "13:11:10" && $2 <= "13:11:20"'  really compares  time range ? Wouldn't  writing a regular expression to  match time range be a right approach to solve this problem some thing like  $2 ~ /^13:11:1[0-9]:[0-9]{3}|13:11:20:[0-9]{3}$/

Answer (score 0):

try below command -

```
awk -F ' ' '($2 >= "13:11:10" && $2 <= "13:11:20") {print substr($2,1,(length($2)-4))}' file
13:11:10
```

if you need to add variables then use below -

```
awk -F ' ' '($2 >= x && $2 <= y) {print substr($2,1,(length($2)-4))}' x="13:11:10" y="13:11:20" file
13:11:10
```

Comment: Thank you only am able to capture is 13:11:10
13:11:10
13:11:11
13:11:11
13:11:15

Comment: am not able to get any info. I mean core information against the  time stamp

Comment: What is the column number for core information or the value of core information ? Use multiple FS using '[ :,]' and use it with print statement OR 
mention the expected output in the Question.. That makes easy to Fellow Stackoverflow member to answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `mktime` in `gawk` [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

```
awk -vstart="13:11:10" -vend="13:11:20" '
    BEGIN{
        gsub(":"," ",start);dtstart=mktime("0 0 0 " start);
        gsub(":"," ",end);dtend=mktime("0 0 0 " end);
    }{
        dt=mktime("0 0 0 " gensub(":"," ","g",$2))
    }dt>=dtstart && dt<=dtend
' JTC.log
```

Comment: thank you.. but its fetching all logs. I mean comp log am getting, not the particular time stamp.

Comment: `*.log` instead of `JCT.log` ? I don't understand you

Comment: What i meant is complete log. Not the prescribed timings